Is it a requirement that Parachain has to use AURA as a block production mechanism?
When I attempted to convert my solo chain into a parachain, I found that Cumulus does not support configuring a parachain with a block production mechanism other than AURA. My question is: Why is AURA required (if it is)? And is it possible to have a hybrid consensus parachain?
Even though I understand that it may not make sense because parachains use the shared security feature of the Relaychain and do not need block finality at the parachain level, I am still curious if there is an alternative mechanism for parachain block producer selection besides AURA.

https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/is-there-any-constrain-forced-on-parachains-for-block-authoring-logic
